# Symfony2: How to create entity form with creation of multiple subentities?

Tags: forms, symfony

This is propably a simple task to solve in Symfony2 but I am really stuck here:

I am building a very simple shop. There are three entities: `Products`, `Customers`, and `Orders`. The last one contains three columns: `customer_id`, `product_id`, and `quantity`. The shop simply consists of a page listing all the products with a select field for each to chose the quantity, followed by a form to enter your customer data.

I have no problem creating the form for the customer data nor listing the products itself (without the select fields).

**But how do I create a form including the select fields of the products, which then should become order entities?**

I played around with form collections and I do understand all the given examples with adding tags to an entity etc. But I can't get the hang of how to adjust it to my situation.

What I have in mind goes something like this:

```
// Create new customer
$customer = new Customer();

// At this point, create form and validate it.
// Having trouble here, need a hint to get it right.
...

// If form is ok, loop thru all the products.
// Since I do not know yet how to define the form,
// I don't know yet what to loop over, too.
foreach( ..... ){
    if($quantity > 0){
        $order = new Order();
        $order->setQuantity($quantity);
        $order->setProduct($product);
        $customer->addOrder($order);
    }
}

// then persist $customer, cascading its orders.
...
```

I have been spending hours on this. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Update:**
Eventually I got it working. I created an `OrderFactory` and a `OrderFormType` and had to change around the whole setting a bit. The AcmePizzaBundle which is mentioned in the responses below was actually a great help to get the missing parts right.

Comment: I'm think you are making this more complicated than it should be.  You need an OrdersFormType which will have a product entity collection (for the list of products) as well as a quantity field.  You then embed a collection of OrdersFormTypes into your CustomerFormType.  But I think you will save yourself some headaches if you follow a more conventional naming pattern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at an example: [AcmePizzaBundle](https://github.com/beberlei/AcmePizzaBundle).
It has 4 entities you need: Pizza, Order,  OrderItem, Customer.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good example in many aspects. However I do know how to create a dynamic order form like in this example. My problem is propably much simpler: How could I list all availabke pizzas from the beginning and then only chose the quantity I want?

Comment: @sprain you mean how to design the cart where a user can choose the quantity?

Comment: Not like a shopping cart, but just a very simple store with quantity selects. Like this: http://sprain.public.s3.amazonaws.com/stuff/simplestore.png
I don't know how to define the form to get this working.

Comment: @sprain Look at Form/Types/OrderItem and Form/Types/Order. And in OrderController::editAction to see how it's used. Otherwise I need more time to make a working example.

Comment: Thanks for your patience :) I did look at the forms and do understand what's happening there. If I keep thinking about my problem described above, I realize that my main issue is actually making a connection between a product listing and the quantity select because they belong to two different entities.

Comment: @sprain that's why you need a new OrderItem entity. It connects a product with an order and lets you set the quantity. With your schema, a customer can buy only one product.

Comment: Ok… I am out of time for today. I'll report back here after I get the chance to give it another try.

Comment: Update: No, the customer can buy more than one product. I don't need customer management so the entites `Customers` and `Orders` are combined in `Customers`. And what's called `OrderItem` is `Orders` in my case. Confusing if compared to the Pizza example, I know.

Comment: Got it working. The AcmePizzaBundle helped me understand the missing parts. Thanks!